# How to add animation to custom button and call whenever button is tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I have created a custom button class which is a subclass of UIButton,
and write an UIButton extension.

Here is my extension:

```
extension UIButton {

    func setButtonCurvy() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2
    }

    //This function should be run when button tapped
    func buttonTapped(_ completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let anim = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        anim.fromValue = 0.9
        anim.toValue = 1.1
        anim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeIn)
        anim.autoreverses = true
        anim.repeatCount = 0
        anim.duration = 1

        self.layer.add(anim, forKey: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.9) {
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

And my class is:

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    //Customize buttons...
    override func awakeFromNib() {

        self.setButtonCurvy()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.mainButtonColor()
        switch self.tag {
        case 1:
            self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Mostley Script", size: 23)
            break
        case 2:
            self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Mostley Script", size: 20)
            break
        default:
            self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Mostley Script", size: 38)
            break
        }
    }

}
```

So here is my problem, I couldn't find in docs, and asked questions. Maybe I just miss something obvious. **Is there any way to call buttonHitted() func, whenever My button is tapped?**

Comment: Call `buttonTapped` method from your action method of button by UIButton's instance.

Comment: You can add action on touchupinside event of UIButton. It will get called whenever you press the button

Comment: Where and How you use `MyButton` ? Please share some code.

Comment: Hello @Mahak Mittal,@Mayur Karmur Of course I know that I can call this func in my action method. However there are tons of classes and buttons, and I don't want to repeat myself.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Said Alır answer by @AtulParmar is nice but if you need to do animation only in case of specific type of event e.g (touchUpInside)then try following solution.

```
import UIKit
class MyButton: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyButton.touchUpInside), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    @objc func touchUpInside() {
        //Perform you animations here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello there thank you for your answer, but as I explained I've tons of classes and tons of buttons and I want to add animation for all of them.. That's why @AtulParmar s solution is much more better for me.. Thank you

Comment: I guess you mistook, method is in UIButton inherited class, meaning you'll have to give one implementation in your custom button class and re-use this button everywhere in whole project for animation everywhere. Even you can extend from UIControl class and can achieve animation in all your other controls. e.g classes inherited from UIDatePicker, UIPageControl, UISegmentedControl, UISlider, UIStepper, UISwitch only implementing method once at single place. ;-)